# Cannot resolve dependency antlr:antlr:2.7.7

Tags: java, maven

I am working on a project for school and I am  trying to make a connection with MySql using Spring Boot but I get this error antlr:antlr:2.7.7 right after I added the dependencies on my IntelliJ project. Here is my pom.xml file:

```xml
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>accessing-data-mysql</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>accessing-data-mysql</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Ask IntelliJ to create a diagram of your pom dependencies and search for antlr.  See which dependency is asking for ANTLR.  Clearly you have not.   ANTLR is up to version 4 in Maven.

Comment: FYI - Latest version of Spring Boot is 2.2.0.RELEASE.

Answer (score 0):

I will say the same what duffymo said. You will get a hierarchy like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fldIG.png)

If there is an issue in generating the hierarchy then do share your stack trace while building and we can find which jar asks for antlr library.

Comment: I know this question might seems a little bit stupid, but how do i generate the hierarchy?I have just installed intellij this week and I don't have any previous  experience with it.